# Implementation of JDBC DataSource in MySQL Connector/J 8

Tags: mysql, jdbc

In the MySQL Connector/J 8.0 [Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/) ([JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for MySQL), I have not found any mention of an implementation for the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface in JDBC.

To quote the `DataSource` Javadoc:

> An alternative to the `DriverManager` facility, a `DataSource` object is the preferred means of getting a connection.

So I would expect an implementation to be provided with Connector/J. For example, for [this Postgres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org), I can find the implementation of `DataSource` in the class [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html), as [discussed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45091981/642706).

➥ Is there no implementation of `DataSource` for *Connector/J*? Or did I miss it?

There is this page, [*6.1 Driver/Datasource Class Name*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html). But, despite the title, mentions only the driver class name, not the class name for a `DataSource` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver has `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` (there is also a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` and an `XADataSource` implementation). The actual implementation of `MysqlDataSource` uses the JDBC driver directly, similar to what `DriverManager` would do.

The MySQL Connector/J hardly mentions data sources. In fact, the only reference I could find to `MysqlDataSource` was in [Changes in the Connector/J API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html). I'm not sure if it is a conscious choice by the MySQL documentation team, but it usually makes little sense to use `MysqlDataSource` directly in your code (it doesn't provide connection pooling), and `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` and `MysqlXADataSource` are not for direct usage nor are they a connection pool (instead they serve as a factory for connections for a Java EE data source that provides connection pooling and/or distributed transactions).

A lot ways of using JDBC involves using third-party data sources providing a connection pool (eg HikariCP, DBCP, c3p0), and those usually use `DriverManager` directly (though some also allow you to provide a data source implementation), or through a data source of a JavaEE/JakartaEE application server. It is usually better to use those than to rely on the data source implementation of a driver.

Comment: Also documented on [*6.3 Configuration Properties*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). Thanks for finding the fully-qualified class name. That is a big help. I’m still looking for the Connector/J Javadoc.

Comment: FYI, the reason to use `DataSource` is not [connection pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), the reason is to *externalize the database connection configuration information*, to be accessed at deployment runtime via [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) rather than [hard-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) within my app. Using `DataSource` is [recommended by Oracle/Sun](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) as the preferred means of getting a connection.

Comment: @BasilBourque Although true, almost all use cases benefit from using a connection pool, and then you use third-party solutions that offers a `DataSource` (like HikariCP, DBCP, c3p0 and others), or built-in in a Java EE/Jakarta EE application server (though those can use a `DataSource`, `ConnectionPoolDataSource` or `XADataSource` of the driver as factory for its connections).

Comment: @BasilBourque I rolled back your edit, because the point of my answer was that although it exists, you probably shouldn't use it, so providing an example how to use it conflicts with that intent.